# Copy and paste based on filter

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to execute a copy and paste function based upon certain criteria being selected.

I have a macro to clear the data in the "NEW PO" tab once an "order" is written and the information is copied to the "POs" tab.

A copy and paste script copies 3 cells from the "NEW PO" tab to the "POs" tab.

```
Sub Copy_Data()

Dim Count, Qty As Long
Dim CatRng, MonthRng, SDate, CxlDate, PoNumb, Vendor As Range
Dim Total As Currency
Dim StrTarget As String
Dim Row, PORow, Col As Integer

Set CatRng = Sheets("NEW PO").Range("G20:G43")
Set MonthRng = Sheets("POs").Range("L122:W122")
StrTarget = Sheets("New PO").Range("V12")
Set SDate = Sheets("New PO").Range("T12")
Set CxlDate = Sheets("New PO").Range("T13")
Set PoNumb = Sheets("New PO").Range("N10")
Set Vendor = Sheets("New PO").Range("D14")
Count = 0

For Count = 0 To 99

    Total = 0
    Qty = 0
    'So that the values reset each time the cat changes

    For Each cell In CatRng
        'To get the row number then total the required information
        If cell.Value = Count Then
            Row = cell.Row
            Qty = Qty + Sheets("NEW PO").Range("S" & Row).Value
            Total = Total + Sheets("NEW PO").Range("Z" & Row).Value
            'I guessed ext cost only as it has been totaled at the bottom,
            'this is easily changed though
        End If
    Next cell

    'Now put the totals into a PO only if there is a quantity of items
    If Qty > 0 Then
        PORow = Sheets("POs").Range("K1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'I'll let you sort the PO number and other fields out but the main 3     are done below
        With Sheets("POs")
            .Range("I" & PORow).Value = Qty
            .Range("K" & PORow).Value = Count
            .Range("C" & PORow).Value = SDate
            .Range("D" & PORow).Value = CxlDate
            .Range("B" & PORow).Value = PoNumb
            .Range("F" & PORow).Value = Vendor
            'My understanding here is that the target month in T12 is in the same format as
            'the anticipated Receipt month, I hope this is what you were looking for

            For Each cell In MonthRng
                If cell.Value = StrTarget Then
                    Col = cell.Column
                    .Cells(PORow, Col).Value = Total
                    'Used .cells here as both column and row are now integers
                    '(only way i can ever get it to work)
                End If
            Next cell

        End With
    End If

Next Count

End Sub
```

I want to filter/validate the quantity (column S) Column Z and extended cost from the "NEW PO" tab based on the **category** selected in Column G. I then want to paste that to the "POs" tab, under the correct month the order is being written, which is determined by the start date in cell T12 on the "NEW PO" tab.

Additionally when the category changes, for example from 00 to 01, it should drop to the next row on the "POs" tab and change category as well.

Screen shots of the two tabs.

[image: PO tab]

[image: New PO Tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to fit what you want it to do, please let me know if it doesn't.

It's a bit long as I just whacked this together between meetings but it does the job. You can use the row and column indexes to manipulate any other data you wish to pull across or amend which cost you want to be totaled up.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Count, Qty As Long
Dim CatRng, MonthRng As Range
Dim Total As Currency
Dim Row, PORow, Col As Integer


Set CatRng = Sheets("NEW PO").Range("G19:G43")
Set MonthRng = Sheets("POs").Range("L122:W122")
Count = 0


    For Count = 0 To 99

    Total = 0
    Qty = 0
    'So that the values reset each time the cat changes

            For Each Cell In CatRng
            'To get the row number then total the required information
                If Cell.Value = Count Then
                Row = Cell.Row
                Qty = Qty + Sheets("NEW PO").Range("T" & Row).Value
                Total = Total + Sheets("NEW PO").Range("AA" & Row).Value
                'I guessed ext cost only as it has been totaled at the bottom,
                'this is easily changed though
                End If
            Next Cell


        'Now put the totals into a PO only if there is a quantity of items
        If Qty > 0 Then
        PORow = Sheets("POs").Range("J1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'I'll let you sort the PO number and other fields out but the main 3 are done below
        With Sheets("POs")
            .Range("I" & PORow).Value = Qty
            .Range("J" & PORow).Value = Count
            'My understanding here is that the target month in T12 is in the same format as
            'the anticipated Receipt month, I hope this is what you were looking for

        For Each Cell In MonthRng
            If Cell.Value = .Range("T12").Value Then
                Col = Cell.Column
                .Cells(PORow, Col).Value = Total
                'Used .cells here as both column and row are now integers
                '(only way i can ever get it to work)
            End If
        Next Cell

        End With
        End If


    Next Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok makes sense. How would I direct the AutoFilter results to the proper cells in the PO's tab? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looking at your explanation above, you appear to be looking for '00' first then '01' and so forth. You want these to be arranged as such i would guess?   Perhaps use a loop counter starting as 00 and increasing by 1 each time. Something like Dim Counter as Long, Counter = 0, in the loop have an if counter equal to or more than 10 then Criteria1:= "=" & Counter Else Criteria1 = "=0" & Counter... Then use the last row formula you already have to find the destination cell. Cant hit next line with any known keyboard shorcuts in this comment field so sorry about the format here.

Comment: Just to clarify (hopefully), the VBA would recognize the Category selected from the drop down in Column G and copy the total quantity in column S and extended cost in Column Z to the last row available in the POs tab is the column for the correct month which can be found on the New Po's tab in cell T12. When the category changes for example from 00 to 01, it should drop to the next row on the PO's tab and change category as well. I have categories from 00-99 as possible options.

Comment: Okay, I think I have got it but Imgur is blocked at work so i can't take a look at your sample data. I will solve this tonight once I get home. I have built the loop that I think is the answer but I need to see your sample data so that I know exactly what it is you want.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm happy to send the document to you as well if needed. I'm quite stuck at this point.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot going on this spreadsheet. A little more description of what's going on will help me out here. I have built a mock of the screenshots you provided. My understanding would be: All of the category 00's totaled from NEW PO to a single PO on the POs tab. Then cat 01's and so forth. I am guessing that then the target month from T12 will be the destination for the total cost? So with the example data, 3 PO's would be made each for 1 quantity but different costs?

Comment: Yes that is all correct. On the New PO's tab and order for products would be written but could contain category 00 and 01 lets say for an order. It could be 20 total items with 10 being category 00 and 10 being category 01. It would be slick if the VBA would capture the total of 00 and 01 and put it in the correct month on the PO's tab. I'm basically trying to make the PO's tab the final destination for all orders. That way the New PO tab can be cleared and start over. Currently these are two separate documents and requires double the work.

Comment: Your script looks great. I have applied it to the document and get no error messages, but it does not seem to be copying anything. I did update a couple of cells/ranges that looked off. I'll keep looking at the code to see where its off.

Here is a link to the two tabs I am working with, maybe you'll see something:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmzr30auj8tzg5a/test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Ok everything is working except for the transfer of the extended cost to the correct month. No extended cost is transferring. I put the corrected VBA in my first post. There is something not working with the recognition of the date in T12 and the month in the POs tab. Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, i'll take a look tomorrow. Was out of the office yesterday and am out for a drink today. I have assumed that T12 is in the format of MMM the same as the momths it is checking. What is the actual output value in T12?

Comment: Anticipated receipt date fields appear in that drop box as '-' but these need to match exactly the output value in T12 for the code to work as it is.

Comment: Ok that sounds like it will solve the issue. I had some cell formate issues when you first sent the code. I didn't bring the file from work and won't be able to check until Tuesday. Thanks for the help and I'll let you know.

Comment: I've verified all the cell formats and it seems to match what is required but I still have no Totals transferring to the POs tab. Here is a document which matches the two tabs I am working with:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8oo4x7ebcdcg0c/test%20new.xlsm?dl=0

I appreciate your help, let me know if you see anything causing this to not work.

Comment: I can't see cell T12, I have to load the dropbox on my phone so I can't play around to find it. What is the output in Cell T12 on the POs tab?

Comment: could try change the if statement to if Month(cell.value) = Month(.Range("T12").Value) and see what that does?

Comment: Error is "argument is not optional" using the new if statement. 

In V12 I put "=T12" and set the value to mmm on the New POs tab. In the PO tab the months in range L122:W122 are also set to mmm format

Comment: ignore the new if statement then. Try changing the range L122:W122 to Jan Feb Mar etc rather that a date with custom format, I believe that's waht I would have done when i knocked up the original code. T12 can be a date in MMM format though as I did tweak this. Very busy today so not going to be able to rebuild it and try anything

Comment: the other if statement should work if both T12 and  range L122:W122 are actual dates that are formatted as MMM as it changes the date value into an integer from 1 to 12 based on the month.

Comment: Ok success sort of. I got it to copy totals but they are going in the wrong month based on the date in T12

For Each cell In MonthRng
           If Month(cell.Value) = Month(.Range("T12").Value) Then
                Col = cell.Column
                .Cells(PORow, Col).Value = Total

Comment: Try changing L122:W122 to text "Jan" "Feb" Mar Apr etc. etc. then use that V12 MMM format you had and dim it as String (called it StrTarget here):    `For Each cell In MonthRng If cell.Value = StrTarget Then Col = cell.Column .Cells(PORow, Col).Value = Total`       Should work... If it answers the query please remember to mark my answer as helpful... i will update the code to reflect this change. Thanks

Comment: Yes that solved the issue! Thanks for all your help! I have updated my original post with the final code.

Comment: Glad I was of help here